Causal additive intervention operation
I am reading the following paper by Shpitser and Pearl: Effects of Treatment on the Treated: Identification and Generalization. On page 517 they provide a corollary concerning the additive intervention operation, denoted by do(x′ + q). They proceed to show that this effect can be estimated with the Effect of Treatment on the Treated (ETT):
$$P(Y|do(X+q)) = \sum_{x'} P(Y_{X+q}=y|x')P(x').$$
While the identification of the ETT seems rather easy, I do not totally understand why we are summing over x' in the first place. I guess it follows from the fact that in the associated graphical model, we are not removing any arrow going into X. Does it mean we cannot remove the summation of the original values of X?

Both expressions here, $\text{do}(X+q)$ and $Y_{X+q}$, with uppercase $X$, are purely symbolic, to represent respectively the policy: adding $q$ to whatever value the variable $X$ is currently having; and the effect of such policy in the distribution of $Y$. It is in fact the following equality the one that brings everything to actual computations:
$$
p(y\mid\text{do}(X+q)) = \sum_{x'}p(Y_{x'+q}=y\mid x')p(x')
$$
This is, to compute the distribution of $Y$, after the policy $\text{do}(X+q)$:

Fix a value of $X=x'$
For all units in the population having the same value $X=x'$, compute the interventional distribution after increasing $X$ from $x'$ to $x'+q$. This result would be conditional only for the chosen subpopulation, this is $p(Y_{x'+q}=y\mid x')$.
Average all subpopulations weighting them against their respective $p(x')$, so one gets: $\sum_{x'}p(Y_{x'+q}=y\mid x')p(x')$.

